# Position Content After a Fixed Navbar?

Tags: css

How can I add content after a fixed navigation bar, without using `margin-top`?

Is it possible?

I tried with `position: relative`, and the `top` property, but I want to do it without this.

Comment: can you post some code or snippet of what you have tried and achieved

Comment: Try padding: 16px;

Comment: Yeh, I understand now what s the problem, once is fixed, it must contain some padding, or top margin, becauese... fixed :))

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
vertical-align: middle;
```

but still it depends... please share webpage or html css of navigation if this will not work.

Comment: here, for I solved, uding position relative, and a top:100px, something like, Idk exactely